# PySpark: unclear error message when using spark.sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `spark.sql` to perform data manipulation as following

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as fun
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
import pandas as pd

dt_orig = spark.read.parquet(file_path)
dt_final = spark.sql("""select * from dt_orig""")
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.2/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 1034, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.2/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.2/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: dt_orig; line 1 pos 14;
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation [dt_orig], [], false
```

Any clue? Thank you.

Comment: the variable [dt_orig] is a dataframe not a table.  You have to post that as a temporary table/view in the current spark session before you reference it.  But why?  Just use display(dt_orig) to show rows.  It gets more interesting if you do not have a "select * from x".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`spark.sql("""select * from dt_orig""")`** here spark defaults to check `dt_orig` table in the database and then check it on the registered view.

As this table doesn't exists in either of place you are getting the error.

---

Register your dataframe as temp view and then query the dataframe data in sql way.

***Try using this syntax:***

```
dt_orig = spark.read.parquet(file_path)
dt_final = dt_orig.createOrReplaceTempView("dt_orig")

#now you can query the dt_orig by using spark sql
spark.sql("select * from dt_orig").show()
```